# Team Foundation Server error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have done some work on a VS 2010 project which is under TFS. I have created a shleveset and want to unshelve the shelveset on another system. But I am getting following error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Multiple errors occurred during the operation, the first of which is displayed below. A full error list is available in the Output Window.

TF203015: The item $/ConsumerCredit/project1/project1.Database/project1.Database.dbproj has an incompatible pending change.
---------------------------
OK
```

How can I fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some guesses:

Look at your list of pending changes. You may already have opened this file for delete or rename or something like that. You can't get the file out of the shelveset because you opened it in the shelveset for something different such as for 'edit'.

You'll probably have to undo your pending change on this file and then get the shelveset.

Or possibly you locked the file when you checked it out on one system, so you can't start editing on the other system (getting it out of the shelveset would adding to your pending files for edit). You could undo the checkout of the file on your first system.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a slight aside to the OP's question**

You can get a TF203015 when you try and batch merge a multiple changesets from one branch to the other without due care.

Consider a situation where you have a MAIN trunk and a DEV branch. You branched DEV from MAIN and have dillegently worked away at a feature in DEV; checking work back into DEV as you progressed. Now fast forward a week or two. You are now feature complete and want to merge back into MAIN.

*This is where one of our devs hit this error.*

He had been woking on one solution for weeks, and checking changesets back into DEV periodically, so wanted to merge a non contiguous series of changesets back into MAIN.
So he picks the merge option, selects the first changeset; merges withoout issue, then immediatley went to merge the next changeset; and bang TF203015, and its very unhelpfull test in teh output window; incompatible pending changes.

After a little fiddling around we now realise what is going on here; the first merge created a pending change in MAIN for the developers solution.  The next merge attempt was also changes to the same solution, which would require TFS to "queue up" a second set of pending changes to the same files.  It cant do this.

So in this scenario TF203015 means; "The destination branch already has pending changes on some files that are changed in this changeset. Please resolve and commit the destination branch changes before perfoming this merge operation"

The solution; after each merge operation our developer tests the workspace for MAIN and commits the pending change caused by the merge, then goes back to DEV and repeats.

Actually sensible and simple, but masked by a very obtuse error message.